# How do I manage merging and rebasing in git?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I git the purpose of rebase. It makes sense to me. Basically i I have a feature branch I'm working on and I'm ready to put it into the master branch I would do a rebase to squash all of my commits into one clean one so that it's easily integrated into master without all the messy history. Right?

Here's what we've been doing.

1. Create a feature branch
2. Add a bunch of commits as we build the feature
3. Periodically merge the master branch into the feature branch (in order to avoid a painful merge down the road)
4. When everything is done, merge feature branch into master

The problem I'm seeing is that periodically merging master into the feature branch causes problems when rebasing because now I have a bunch of master branch checkins mixed in amongst my feature checkins.

What's the right workflow here? Where do the following commads come into play:

- git rebase -i Head^#
- git rebase master
- git merge master
- git-rerere
- git reset --hard HEAD^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only merge to/from master once, at the end of life of the branch.  The idea of a feature/topic branch is that it only contains changes relevant to the feature; you lose that when you merge in master repeatedly.  (You can read what [Junio Hamano, the git maintainer, says about branches](http://gitster.livejournal.com/42247.html).)

You can do a "practice" merge, that you will throw away, and use `git-rerere` to have Git automatically record your merge resolutions, so that they can be re-used when you really are ready to merge.  See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html for background and tutorial.  This is really cool because it lets you do the work of the merge, without committing it anywhere explicitly, and then get that work back "magically" when you really are ready to create the merge.  So, instead of one big painful merge at the end, you can do a bunch of smaller, hopefully simpler, intermediate "practice" merges along the way.  Roughly speaking:

```
# Enable rerere
git config --global rerere.enabled 1
# Start a feature branch
git checkout -b feature
# Hack hack hack
git commit
git commit
# Practice merge
git merge master
# ...then throw the merge commit away, the work is saved by rerere
git reset --hard HEAD^
# Hack hack hack
git commit
# Really merge to master, reusing any saved work from rerere
git checkout master
git merge feature
git branch -d feature
```

See also http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html for another tutorial.

You can also periodically rebase your topic branch on top of master and then just do a merge at the end.

To deal with a situation like the one where you are currently in, with a topic branch (say named `feature`) that has a series of merges from main mixed with various in-progress commits, the easiest approach would be to do a squashed merge to produce a "merged" working tree and then create a new commit (or series of commits) on to main.  For example:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature
git commit
```

This will produce a single commit that represents the state of the tree at the head of feature, merged into master.

Of course, you can also just do a regular merge to `master` for this change, leaving the messy history of `feature` present, and just work more cleanly in the future. e.g., simply

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

and move on.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. I've never heard git-rerere. I read the man page and it kinda makes sense, but I'm lost on how to work it. So rebasing is used to not only squash commits, but also set to move the intial origin branch forward? I'm so confused. What's the actual process I should be employing here? Particularly for long running branches.

Comment: You shouldn't need rerere. Just rebase against master as you go along so that the conflicting topic branch commits are fixed going forward.

Comment: which rebase command should I use? In the past I've tried `git rebase master` and it replays all my commits on top of master along with a million merge conflicts. It takes forever and at the end, I'm never sure that I merged properly.

Comment: git-rerere is a tool that helps you manage repeated merges while preserving the "theory" that a topic branch should be clean.  In your current case where you have a branch with many merges from main, the cleanest thing to do is to `git checkout master` and then `git merge --squash yourbranchname` which will do a merge back to master, but throw away the merge history.  In the future, you can either practice merge and use git-rerere to help, or simply frequently rebase your topic branch on top of master.

Comment: I would be interested in the actual commands here if anyone can supply.  Given a Master branch named master and a feature branch named feature would one switch to the feature branch and type git rebase master and then switch to the master branch and type git merge feature?

Comment: So what happens if I decide to pull out the feature after it has been merged in to `master`?. Will I lose all the commits that were merged into `feature` and then sqaushed? Also, if I can squash into 1 commit nicely, what's the purpose of rebase?

Comment: You can use `git revert` to revert any commit, merge or not.  A `merge --squash` is not a true merge; it discards any commits originally on the `feature` branch and simply allows you to create a new commit on master that has the *contents* of the HEAD of `feature`.  Rebase allows you to squash but the real use of rebase is to take the changes you have created on `feature` and replay them on top of master.

Comment: do what the response said. Even when rebasing onto a new point as dahlbyk said, you will need rerere as you will potentiall face the same conflicts when rebasing over and over again. You don't want to add this manual work.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand rerere completely.  Our practice on feature branches has been to merge master into the feature branch on a daily or regular basis so as not to have one giant merge nightmare at the end of the feature.  It seems as though rerere is designed to let you do this, record you conflict resolutions, but then discard the merge, and when you do a final merge at the end of the feature your conflict resolutions are all 'replayed' for you?

Comment: @Tom that's what I'm getting out of this too. What is the actual `git-rerere` command do? @Emil I noticed you're not actually using `rebase` anywhere. Is the `rerere` and `test merges` in place of rebasing? Is this safe to do on a shared branch?

Comment: @Tom: That restatement is correct.  @Micah: The `git-rerere` command, once enabled, is typically invisible to you.  Using `rerere` and test merges are safe to do on a shared branch---safer in some sense than rebasing since that means you're not doing a forced update, though the test merges and recorded resolutions will not be visible to the rest of your team.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to rebase (which I suggest you do), then don't ever merge from master. A rebase workflow is based on the idea that a topic branch consists of the path from master to the new feature and nothing else. As master moves forward, then your changes to get toward the new feature move with it.

When you're finally ready to bring the changes into master, you have a two main options:

1. Rebase against master one final time, then do a normal fast-forward merge which essentially brings all your branch's commits into master one by one. This keeps a more granular history, but if intermediate commits broke the build then you may prefer to squash them. Interactive rebase (-i) can help arrange these commits.
2. Use merge --squash to make a single commit in master that contains all the branch's changes.

Comment: That pretty much covers simple cases, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to rebase the branch anyway, just rebase whenever you want to "merge" changes in. You don't have to rebase + squash until you're ready to "merge" that branch into master.

Comment: @adymitruk: Well, all you have to do is enable rerere, then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the short answer is:

use `git merge --squash` if:

if you have a feature branch and you are pulling from another branch into that branch as you work, for instance you switch to feature and run git merge master periodically to merge in the master branch.  Or you are pulling or pushing that branch to others or to a central repo like github.

use `git rebase` if:

if you have a feature branch that you are not pushing or pulling to others, and you are not merging another branch into periodically, as described above